# How to make range number value on TextField() Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code :

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: TextField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.assessment),
                    hintText: "Nilai",
                    border: InputBorder.none),
                onChanged: (String str) {
                  nilai = str;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

> How to make the input number like only range 1 - 20?

I'm try to using

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[1-20]")),
```

but, because this WhitelistingTextInputFormatter RegExp type is string, then I can still type 22 because 2 is allowed there.

Comment: You can use custom input validation on "OnChange" method.

Comment: This is one example: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-set-min-max-value-for-textfield-textformfield

Answer (score 19):

The top upvoted answer exhibits some odd behavior when you type a number and then delete it (e.g. if you try typing in a new number it stops working).

I made a slightly altered TextInputFormatter that let's you specify the min and max and fixes some of the weird behaviors from the original answer.

```
class NumericalRangeFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final double min;
  final double max;

  NumericalRangeFormatter({required this.min, required this.max});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {

    if (newValue.text == '') {
      return newValue;
    } else if (int.parse(newValue.text) < min) {
      return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: min.toStringAsFixed(2));
    } else {
      return int.parse(newValue.text) > max ? oldValue : newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While the logic is working well, it should be noted the `else if` block will set the cursor to before the value being returned. If you'd like to change this behavior, replace `TextEditingValue().copyWith(...)` with `newValue.copyWith(...)`. This sets the cursor after the returned value and allows the user to backspace immediately instead of having to adjust the cursor then delete their value.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement you own `TextInputFormatter` by extending the `TextInputFormatter` class and then implementing the `formatEditUpdate()` method.

Here is an example for you use case -

```
class CustomRangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue,TextEditingValue newValue,) { 
    if(newValue.text == '')
      return TextEditingValue();
    else if(int.parse(newValue.text) < 1)
      return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: '1');

    return int.parse(newValue.text) > 20 ? TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: '20') : newValue;
  }
}
```

And you can add the custom formatter to the `TextField` like so -

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    CustomRangeTextInputFormatter(),
  ],
  // Rest of the TextField code
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This one work for me just litte chage, it change cursor position, so i added this line

return int.parse(newValue.text) > 20 ? TextEditingValue(selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: max.toString().length),).copyWith(text: '20') : newValue;

Answer (score 2):

```
keyboardType:
   TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters:[                        //only numeric keyboard.
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),      //only 6 digit
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
  ],
```

> hope this will help you

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `onChanged` by:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
    try {
        if(int.parse(value) >= 1 && int.parse(value) <= 20) {
            nilai = value;
        }
    } catch (e) {}
```

Comment: thanks buddy, but this is for the result I think I need some code that works while still typing.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you use a ```TextFormField``` inside a ```Form```, you specify your custom validation in the ```validator``` and set the ```autovalidate``` property to ```true```. If you do not like the autovalidation. You could set a ```TextEditingController``` and add a listener to it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use clamp when text changes:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
  ],
  onChanged: (value) {
    final number = int.tryParse(value);
    if (number != null) {
      final text = number.clamp(min, max).toString();
      final selection = TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: text.length,
      );
      textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(
        text: text,
        selection: selection,
      );
    }
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int.parse(value.toString()) < rangoMinimo ? 'El valor debe de ser mayor o igual a ${rangoMinimo}' : int.parse(value.toString()) > rangoMaximo ? 'El valor debe de ser menor o igual a ${rangoMaximo}' : null : null
```

Answer (score 0):

To make phone set limit of phone input
you can make use of inputFormatter method as

```
inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  ],
```

this will allow you input digits only, and max length of 11 characters.
Further, if you want to validate on user interaction, and also be sure the user inputs nothing less than 11 characters you can do something like

```
   validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return fetchErrorText(expectedTextVariable: "phone");
                    }
                    if (value.length != 11) {
                      return fetchErrorText(expectedTextVariable: 'phone length');
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
```

The fetchErrorText is a simple method that returns a Strings. It returns defined error text that macthes each case in the validation block.
I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a property available for Max length `maxLength: 20` so you can use this

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
  child: TextField(
    inputFormatters: [
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    ],
    maxLength: 20,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.assessment),
        hintText: "Nilai",
        border: InputBorder.none),
    onChanged: (String str) {
      nilai = str;
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks, but maxLenght is equal with LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2), and that was for lenght not range of value