# how to limit the user to enter number outside the given range(says 1 to 4000) in flutter textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-textformfield

Restricts the user's input.
For example, if I set the numeric limit to 4000, the user cannot enter a number greater than 4000.

```
TextFormField(
                //TODO:보유수량 이상 쓰는것 방지할것.
                controller: _recruitStockEditingController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 21.0.w, top: 11.0.h, bottom: 11.0.h),
                    hintText: "수량을 입력해주세요.",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0.sp, color: const Color(0xff696C75)),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffCACBD4)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6))),
              ),
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836681/how-to-make-range-number-value-on-textfield-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try this with TextInputFormatter

   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

   ```
    class NumberLimitFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
      @override
      TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
        if(newValue.text == "") return newValue;
        if(int.parse(newValue.text.toString())<4000){
          return newValue;
        }
        return oldValue;
      }
    }
   ```

Uasge:

```
TextField(
              controller: myController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  NumberLimitFormatter(),
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                 ],
            ),
```

2. Using Validator and TextFormField:

```
 TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
            .onUserInteraction, // to instantly valid the input
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        ],
        validator: (String? value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty)
            return "Enter number";
          else if (int.parse(value) > 4000)
            return "Entered number can't be greater than 4000";
          else
            return null;
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a validator.

```
    validator: (value) {
    if (value > 4000) {
      return "You can't enter a value greater than 4000";
    }
    return null;
  },
```